# Android - Google play - enable download app for devices that supports opengl extension

Tags: android, opengl-es2, google-play

I am using OpenGL ES 2 in my game. However, for simplicity i have used some extensions like VAO. Is there a way, how to disable dowloading of my app for devices, that do not support this (and other) extensions?

I can check it in code, but that is a little late, when user already bought my game and it wont work.

Answer (score 1):

A quick solution is to require OpenGL ES3, by specifying in the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00030000"/>
```

But that will reduce the number of compatible devices.
The good news is that the majority of devices that are active on Google Play support ES3.

Less than 37% of the devices (as of oct 2017) are still on ES2.
And that number will continue to drop.

https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html